# feasible region of an inequality verification

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry

### Can the following inequality be simplified as follows.

$ t_1-2t_2\leq 5  ----(1)$

$-3t_1+2t_2\leq 1---(2)$

$(1)+(2) \rightarrow$
$ 2t_1\leq6$
$t_1\geq-3$

and
$3*(1)+(2) \rightarrow t_2\geq-4$
now consider the point **(1,-3)** It satisfies the above two conditions. Where $t_1=1$and $t_2=-3$

**BUT** If we draw the graph and find out the feasible region (as attached) that point if not within the feasible area. Please help me to verify this confusion
[image]

Comment: It is true that $(1)(2)\implies t_1\ge -3,t_2\ge -4$, but the converse is not true.

Comment: Thank you. So simply does it mean that we cannot simplify the inequalities as we do for simultaneous equations and obtain the solutions

Comment: To add to the comment above, the feasible region is a subset of the region defined by derived inequalities.